# How are ad-hoc servers requiring TLS usually implemented?

Tags: ssl, server, lets-encrypt

I have a main server which serves all incoming traffic to https://www.example.com.  The main server assigns the client a secondary server to make a persistent secure WebSocket connection.

These secondary servers may be started and stopped on an ad-hoc basis (depending on how crowded the existing secondary servers are), and they will be given a new public IP address when started (perhaps using AWS or Linode-like cloud hosting services).  Upon startup, the secondary server will authenticate with the main server, and tell the main server its public IP address (so that the main server can inform incoming clients).

To use a secure WebSocket (wss://) connection, I will need to get a certificate for that server, which probably means I need a sub-domain name to give to each secondary server.  But domain names take quite a while to propagate through the Internet, so I won't be able to instantaneously start and use the server.

Unless I get a certificate using the IP address only (meaning that my secondary servers will not have a domain name).  Which doesn't seem very secure since cloud hosting services do not retain a fixed IP address upon shutdown of the server.

For my certificate authority, I'm using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) because I'm running an online game where the data going across the WebSocket connection isn't really sensitive.

This whole thing seems too complicated to be the right way to set up TLS on my servers.

How should this be properly done?  Is there a way to just launch a secondary server instance, and have it set up TLS all automatically?  Or should I just forget it all and not use TLS for the secondary servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly name "Propagation" isn't real, or rather, it's a legend based only loosely on the facts about DNS caching. If you're serious about this game spinning up servers and tearing them down in real time you will eventually need to learn (or need to hire someone who knows) about this stuff. If you've gotten the idea that "propagation" takes hours, or even days, that'll be from using cheap web-hosting which can't be bothered to offer better service because it doubts you know the difference.

The simplest way to do this, if this is going to be some big service with lots of servers spinning up and being torn down, is to buy a wildcard certificate, that is, one which says *.example.com and works for any server named anything.example.com (no extra dots though, be aware of that, it won't work for something.subdomain.example.com because of the extra dot). Let's Encrypt does not offer wildcards, but, they're not terribly expensive if you only need one to run your whole service.

On the other hand if you're doing things on the cheap, use Let's Encrypt's DNS-01 validation method to let you issue a certificate for a suite of server names in advance of knowing what their addresses will be. So maybe you use this validation to get a certificate listing server01.example.com, server02.example.com and so on up to server40.example.com, you can now use this certificate (and the accompanying private key) for any machines with any of those names that gets spun up. This way of doing things isn't ideal security-wise, but you say you don't care too much about that.

Using the DNS-01 method means you don't need to have the servers actually working when the certificate is issued, just control over their DNS records. You need to figure out the rough number of servers you might need somewhat in advance, but frankly if you're building a game not sure if it'll have five players or five million players, chances are your worst problems aren't going to be with TLS.

Comment: After reading your answer and realizing that stackoverflow.com doesn't use TLS (apart from the sign-in page), I think I'll just not use TLS, until maybe I need an account system.  Thanks!